# Prove that $\sum\limits_{\mathrm{cyc}} \frac{a^2 + a b + 2 a + b^2 + 3}{a^2 + a b - 2 a + b^2 + 3} \le 6$ for $a, b, c \ge 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> I have already post this inequality but I add this condition $a,b,c\geq 1$
> $$6\geq \frac{a^2 + a b + 2 a + b^2 + 3}{a^2 + a b - 2 a + b^2 + 3}+\frac{c^2 + c b + 2 b + b^2 + 3}{c^2 + c b - 2 b + b^2 + 3}+\frac{a^2 + a c + 2 c + c^2 + 3}{a^2 + a c - 2 c + c^2 + 3}$$

I try many classical inequalities but without success...
My try :

We study the following function :
$$f(x)=\frac{x^2+x+2x+3+1}{x^2+x-2x+3+1}+\frac{x^2+x+2+3+1}{x^2+x-2+3+1}+2$$

It's decreasing and the maximum is reached for $x=1$ and is equal to 6.

Now we put :

$$x= \frac{(\sqrt{4 a^3 + 4 a^2 b - 15 a^2 + 4 a b^2 + 12 a} - a)}{2 a}$$

We get :

$$f(x)=\frac{(a^2+b^2+ab+3+2a)}{(a^2+b^2+ab+3-2a)}+2+\frac{(a^2 + \sqrt{a (4 a b + a (4 a - 15) + 4 b^2 + 12)} + ab-a + b^2 + 3)}{(a^2 - \sqrt{a (4 a b + a (4 a - 15) + 4 b^2 + 12)} + a b + a + b^2 + 3)} $$

So if $a\geq b \geq c$ and if we suppose:$\quad$    $max(\frac{a^2 + a b + 2 a + b^2 + 3}{a^2 + a b - 2 a + b^2 + 3};\frac{c^2 + c b + 2 b + b^2 + 3}{c^2 + c b - 2 b + b^2 + 3})=\frac{a^2 + a b + 2 a + b^2 + 3}{a^2 + a b - 2 a + b^2 + 3}$ it remains to prove that we have :

$$\frac{(a^2 + \sqrt{a (4 a b + a (4 a - 15) + 4 b^2 + 12)} + ab-a + b^2 + 3)}{(a^2 - \sqrt{a (4 a b + a (4 a - 15) + 4 b^2 + 12)} + a b + a + b^2 + 3)}\geq \frac{a^2 + a b + 2 a + b^2 + 3}{a^2 + a b - 2 a + b^2 + 3}$$

Wich is true for $b\geq2$ because we have with this condition :
$$\sqrt{a (4 a b + a (4 a - 15) + 4 b^2 + 12)}-a\geq 2a$$

Edit : I have the end of my proof but it's ugly...Now we know that the inequality is true .

Have you easier ?

Thanks a lot .

Comment: I would start with $a=b=c$ and prove that, to get a better intuition for the inequality. Then take without loss of generality (since the three fractions are similar) $a>b>c$ and see how far you can get. If you provide us with more information on what you tried so far, everyone here is more encouraged to help you.

Comment: No problem I will post my try very soon .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Resubstitute $a \to 1+a$, $b \to 1+b$, $c \to 1+c$.

Then you have $a,b,c\geq 0$ and you need to show

$$
6\geq \sum_{cyclic}\frac{a^2 + a b + 5 a + b^2 + 3 b + 8}{a^2 + a b + a + b^2 + 3 b + 4}
$$

or

$$
 \frac34 - \sum_{cyclic}\frac{1+a}{a^2 + a b + a + b^2 + 3 b + 4} \geq
 0$$

Full expansion gives

$$
 \frac{N}{4 (a^2 + a b + a + b^2 + 3 b + 4) (a^2 + a c + 3 a + c^2 + c + 4) (b^2 + b c + b + c^2 + 3 c + 4)} \geq 0
$$

with

$$
 N = 3 a^4 b^2 + 3 a^4 b c  + 3 a^4 c^2 + 9 a^4 c + 8 a^4 + 3 a^3 b^3 + 6 a^3 b^2 c + 7 a^3 b^2 + 6 a^3 b c^2 + 16 a^3 b c + 3 a^3 c^3 + 17 a^3 c^2 + 32 a^3 c + 16 a^3 + 3 a^2 b^4 + 6 a^2 b^3 c + 17 a^2 b^3 + 9 a^2 b^2 c^2 + 24 a^2 b^2 c + 15 a^2 b^2 + 6 a^2 b c^3 + 24 a^2 b c^2 + 65 a^2 b c + 17 a^2 b + 3 a^2 c^4 + 7 a^2 c^3 + 15 a^2 c^2 + 23 a^2 c + 8 a^2 + 3 a b^4 c + 9 a b^4 + 6 a b^3 c^2 + 16 a b^3 c + 32 a b^3 + 6 a b^2 c^3 + 24 a b^2 c^2 + 65 a b^2 c + 23 a b^2 + 3 a b c^4 + 16 a b c^3 + 65 a b c^2 + 120 a b c + 40 a b  + 17 a c^2 + 40 a c + 3 b^4 c^2  + 8 b^4 + 3 b^3 c^3 + 7 b^3 c^2 + 16 b^3 + 3 b^2 c^4 + 17 b^2 c^3 + 15 b^2 c^2 + 17 b^2 c + 8 b^2 + 9 b c^4 + 32 b c^3 + 23 b c^2 + 40 b c + 8 c^4 + 16 c^3 + 8 c^2 - (a^4 b +  b^4 c + c^4 a) \geq 0
$$

to be established. Though this may look awkward, the only terms of concern are the last three negative terms - everything else is nonnegative.  For the negative terms, we can apply quadratic completion with the other terms including fourth powers. For the terms with $a^4$, we see easily that

$$
3 a^4 b^2 + 3 a^4 b c  + 3 a^4 c^2 + 9 a^4 c + 8 a^4 - a^4 b \\
= 2 a^4 b^2 + 3 a^4 b c  + 3 a^4 c^2 + 9 a^4 c + 7 a^4 + a^4 b  + a^4 \cdot (b -1 )^2 \ge 0
$$

By cyclicity in $(a,b,c)$, this holds likewise for the terms with $b^4$ and $c^4$.  This completes the proof.

Comment: holy crap man. if i had been asked to solve this ineq i would have died, congrats!!!! incredible solution.

Answer (score 1):

The given inequality can be transformed into 
$$\sum \frac {a^2+b^2+ab+2a+3}{a^2+b^2+ab-2a+3}\le 6$$

Which changes to 
$$\sum 1+\frac {4a}{a^2+b^2+ab-2a+3}\le 6$$
$$\Rightarrow \sum  \frac {4a}{a^2+b^2+ab-2a+3}\le 3$$
Hence it suffices to show that 
$$\sum \frac {a}{a^2+b^2+ab-2a+3}\le \frac{3}{4}$$
Hence by AM GM we have LHS as 
$$\sum \frac {a}{3(ab+1)-2a}$$
Again by AM GM LHS becomes
$$\sum \frac {a}{6\sqrt {ab}-2a}=\sum \frac {1}{6\sqrt {\frac {b}{a}}-2}$$

Hence it suffices to show that

$$\sum \frac {1}{3\sqrt {\frac {b}{a}}-1}\le \frac {3}{2}$$

That means 
$$\frac {1}{3\sqrt {\frac {b}{a}}-1}+    \frac {1}{3\sqrt {\frac {c}{b}}-1}+   \frac {1}{3\sqrt {\frac {c}{a}}-1}\le \frac {3}{2}$$

I hope you can take it from here.